# How to use uitextfield for searching places in google maps sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, search, uitextfield

I Am using googlemapssdk in my app instead of mapkit,how I have a text field I have to use that textfield for searching places in the google maps.

How to use text for searching places in the googlemaps sdk and how to get the searched place latitude and longitude of that particular place.

I have gone through all the questions in the stack overflow but I can't able to understand them so please help me out to solve this problem.

Thanks for quick Answers.

Comment: google itself provides some api for autocomplete search you can use those to get lat long and more.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply vaibhav,how to use textfelid for searching and where can I get the apis can you please give a link for that and how to use that apis.

Comment: see this https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=ssl#q=google+places+autocomplete+api+example+ios.

Comment: take a look in https://gitlab.doc.ic.ac.uk/jr1313/londonloop/tree/a97166e00d12826478f07bf3e41430dc838b2d9e/Pods/GoogleMaps/GoogleMapsSDKDemos/SDKDemos/PlacesSamples

Comment: @chiraj thanks for your reply   how search places using uitextfield

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//You can perform search by tapping search button using the following code
- (IBAction)searchButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self searchForLocationWithText:self.searchTextField.text];
}


//Else If you want to perform the search on typing each letter, You can use this delegate method
- (void)textFieldDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [self searchForLocationWithText:self.searchTextField.text];
}


//Method for searching
- (void)searchForLocationWithText:(NSString *)searchString{
    GMSCoordinateBounds *bounds = [self getGMSBoundsWithRadiusInMeters:10000];
    GMSAutocompleteFilter *filter = [[GMSAutocompleteFilter alloc] init];
    filter.country=@"IN";

    [place_client autocompleteQuery:searchString bounds:bounds filter:filter callback:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
        //Process result
    }];

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time,if i only this method for google maps seearching will it work or do i want and additional methods,

Comment: @SatheeshkumarNaidu : I have just added code for making search with the text in the textField, and as per the above code it will give you the results and you have to handle those results like loading in local array and displaying it in the tableView like that. Rest I hope you will understand and take care of.

Comment: the search result i have to show in google maps,for example if i search India i have show India in google maps.for this do you sugest any code

Comment: @SatheeshkumarNaidu : I hope it works in the way that when you search for particular text it will show you the results. You have to select any particular result item and load it in the map. But not as you asked now.

Comment: But in our requirement it is like when you search some place in the textfield you have get the lat and log of that position and we have send that lat and log to backend from back end they will provide me some lat and lag and i want print it in the map,for example if search bangalore i textfiled I have send lat and log of bangalore to backend then they will send some lat and log say list of malls in the bangalore the i have show them in the map view

Comment: @SatheeshkumarNaidu : You can achieve this in two steps, 1. Search for a text using the above code, you will get results(Array of GMSAutocompletePrediction) items. 2. You have to choose a particular item/place from the result to get the CLLocationCoordinate2D(co-ordinates) (you can find this code in google map iOS documentation). Then you can send it to your backend as you want to. But I don't find a way to directly do what you have asked.